# Use RegEx In JQuery Validate Plugin To Ensure No Illegal Characters In Folder Name

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use a RegEx to ensure that users don't put any illegal Windows characters in their folder name that gets created (Yes, I check server-side before creating the folder as well), and I'd like to use JQuery's Validate plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/) to do this, but all the RegEx examples seem to point me toward making sure that what the user enters MATCHES, rather than DOES NOT MATCH. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Here's my JQuery Code (ironically, it works in reverse - if I enter one of the illegal characters, it's fine, but if I take it out, it triggers the validation):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.validator.addMethod(
"regex",
function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /:|\?|\\|\*|\"|<|>|\||%/g.test(value);
},
    "Asserter Names Cannot Contain Certain Characters.");

$('#matterDetail').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        "Asserter": {
        required: true,
        regex: true,
        minlength: 2
        }
    }
});
});
```

I got the regex rule from here: http://RegExr.com?2rj55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use !() to reverse your rule...

```
return this.optional(element) || !(/:|\?|\\|\*|\"|<|>|\||%/g.test(value));
```